# Problem with longtable environment: code not compiled

Tags: longtable

I am writing a table for my PhD thesis, but it is a bit too long to fit one page. I tried to use the package *longtable* to split it into two pages, but Latex does not compile it, and I do not understand why.

Here the code of my "normal" table:

```
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\caption{Overview of the samples in the corpus of artists' materials.}
\label{table:corpus_artists_materials}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Reference samples}} \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Synthesized ZnO & ZnO nanosmoke synthesized  \\
 & as in Zhang et al. (2020) \cite{zhangControlled2020} \\
\midrule                                                                                    
\textit{Br\"uggemann} & Two powders (2020, indirect and direct method) \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ZnO manufacturers}} \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
KF Chemicals & One powder (historical) \\ 
Japan, since 1951 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                             
\midrule
Kremer & Two powders (2010 and 2021) \\
Germany, since 1977 &  \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Maastrichtsche zinkwit Maatschappij & Five powders of different grades (1907-1989) \\
The Netherlands, 1870-1989\footnote{Then acquired by the \textit{Vieille Montagne}.} & \\                                                                                                       
\midrule
Merck & One powder (historical) \\
Germany, since 1668 & \\                                                                                                                                                                                                          \midrule
Sikkens & One powder (historical) \\
The Netherlands, since 1792 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                               \midrule 
Vieille Montagne & Six powders of different grades (1847-1989) \\
Belgium, 1837-1989\footnote{Then Union Minière, today Umicore.} &  \\                                                                                                                                        \midrule  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Colour manufacturers}} \\   
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Blockx & Two paint tubes (1976 and 2021) \\
Belgium, since 1865 & One titan-zinc white paint tube (2021) \\
\midrule
Bocour & One paint tube (1933-75) \\
US, since 1932 & One titan-zinc white paint jar (1940-75) \\
\midrule
Charvin & One paint tube (2010) \\
France, since 1830 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                            \midrule
Craftint Manufacturing Company & One paint tube (1950s) \\
US, 1929-2018 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                         \midrule
Fezandie \& Sperrle & One powder (historical) \\
US, until 1979 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                  \midrule
Grumbacher & Three paint tubes (1950s and two tubes from1960-75) \\
US, since 1905\footnote{Today in Chartpark, Inc.} &  \\                                                                                                                                      
\midrule
Lefranc & One paint tube (1930s) \\
France, 1720-1964\footnote{Then Lefranc \& Bourgeois.} & one paint sample (1950) \\
 & One powder with a binder (before 1964) \\
\midrule
Lefranc \& Bourgeois & Two paint tubes (after 1964, 2021) \\
France, since 1964 & One pastel (after 1964) \\
\midrule
Maimeri & One paint sample from a color chart (1939-46) \\
Italy, since 1923\footnote{In Fila group since 2014.} & One paint tube (1970s) \\
\midrule
Michael Harding & One paint tube (2021) \\
US, since 1982 &  \\
\midrule
Old Holland & One paint tube (2010) \\
The Netherlands, since 1664 &  \\
\midrule
Permanent Pigments & One powder (1933-55) \\
US, 1933-55 & One paint tube (1933-55) \\
\midrule
Ripolin & One paint sample from a color chart (1900) \\
France, since 1888 &  \\
\midrule
Sennelier & Two powders (after 1887, 2021) \\
France, since 1887 & Two paint tubes (after the 1920s, 2021) \\
\midrule
Talens & Two paint tubes (1930s)\footnote{From the same box: one in good condition, the other yellowed and dried.} \\
The Netherlands, 1889-1969\footnote{Then \textit{Sikkens} group, then \textit{Akzo Nobel}.} &  \\
\midrule
Vilhelm Pacht & One paint tube (1890-1909) \\
Denmark, since 1887 &  \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                           
Winsor \& Newton & One paint tube (2021) \\
UK, since 1832 &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here is the compiled table: [image: Compiled table]

That's the result I would like to have, but as you can see, the table is too long. I would like to ask Latex to split it into a new page, repeating the headers "Brand" and "Samples".
Here is the code for the longtable that I tried without success:

```
\begin{longtable}{cc} % Two columns
\caption{Overview of the samples in the corpus of artists' materials.}
\label{table:corpus_artists_materials}
\toprule
\textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Samples} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Samples} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Reference samples}} \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Synthesized ZnO & ZnO nanosmoke synthesized  \\
 & as in Zhang et al. (2020) \cite{zhangControlled2020} \\
\midrule                                                                                    
\textit{Br\"uggemann} & Two powders (2020, indirect and direct method) \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ZnO manufacturers}} \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
KF Chemicals & One powder (historical) \\ 
Japan, since 1951 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                             
\midrule
Kremer & Two powders (2010 and 2021) \\
Germany, since 1977 &  \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Maastrichtsche zinkwit Maatschappij & Five powders of different grades (1907-1989) \\
The Netherlands, 1870-1989\footnote{Then acquired by the \textit{Vieille Montagne}.} & \\                                                                                                       
\midrule
Merck & One powder (historical) \\
Germany, since 1668 & \\                                                                                                                                                                                                          \midrule
Sikkens & One powder (historical) \\
The Netherlands, since 1792 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                               \midrule 
Vieille Montagne & Six powders of different grades (1847-1989) \\
Belgium, 1837-1989\footnote{Then Union Minière, today Umicore.} &  \\                                                                                                                                        \midrule  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Colour manufacturers}} \\   
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Blockx & Two paint tubes (1976 and 2021) \\
Belgium, since 1865 & One titan-zinc white paint tube (2021) \\
\midrule
Bocour & One paint tube (1933-75) \\
US, since 1932 & One titan-zinc white paint jar (1940-75) \\
\midrule
Charvin & One paint tube (2010) \\
France, since 1830 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                            \midrule
Craftint Manufacturing Company & One paint tube (1950s) \\
US, 1929-2018 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                         \midrule
Fezandie \& Sperrle & One powder (historical) \\
US, until 1979 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                  \midrule
Grumbacher & Three paint tubes (1950s and two tubes from1960-75) \\
US, since 1905\footnote{Today in Chartpark, Inc.} &  \\                                                                                                                                      
\midrule
Lefranc & One paint tube (1930s) \\
France, 1720-1964\footnote{Then Lefranc \& Bourgeois.} & one paint sample (1950) \\
 & One powder with a binder (before 1964) \\
\midrule
Lefranc \& Bourgeois & Two paint tubes (after 1964, 2021) \\
France, since 1964 & One pastel (after 1964) \\
\midrule
Maimeri & One paint sample from a color chart (1939-46) \\
Italy, since 1923\footnote{In Fila group since 2014.} & One paint tube (1970s) \\
\midrule
Michael Harding & One paint tube (2021) \\
US, since 1982 &  \\
\midrule
Old Holland & One paint tube (2010) \\
The Netherlands, since 1664 &  \\
\midrule
Permanent Pigments & One powder (1933-55) \\
US, 1933-55 & One paint tube (1933-55) \\
\midrule
Ripolin & One paint sample from a color chart (1900) \\
France, since 1888 &  \\
\midrule
Sennelier & Two powders (after 1887, 2021) \\
France, since 1887 & Two paint tubes (after the 1920s, 2021) \\
\midrule
Talens & Two paint tubes (1930s)\footnote{From the same box: one in good condition, the other yellowed and dried.} \\
The Netherlands, 1889-1969\footnote{Then \textit{Sikkens} group, then \textit{Akzo Nobel}.} &  \\
\midrule
Vilhelm Pacht & One paint tube (1890-1909) \\
Denmark, since 1887 &  \\
\midrule                                                                                                                                                                                           
Winsor \& Newton & One paint tube (2021) \\
UK, since 1832 &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Thank you so much!!!

Comment: do not show only snippets. Always show a small but complete document that demonstrates your issue. And it also help if you mention what "without success" actually means, e.g. if you get an error or if it only doesn't look like you want.

Comment: The `\\ ` after `\caption{…}\label{…}` is missing. Maybe you also have to remove the empty lines aka pars.

Comment: "without success" is hard to debug, show the document that you used and show the exact error from the log.

Comment: It works, thank you! But the table is larger than the margins of the page. Not sure if it is like this by default or due to the text.

Comment: @Nico, you receive two answers. Does any of them solve your problem? If yes, please accept one (by clicking on the check mark at te top left side of selected answer), which done this to your opinion on the best way!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `longtable` with `xltabular`. It enable to prescribe table width and broke to long test into several text lines:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}} % Two columns
\caption{Overview of the samples in the corpus of artists' materials.}
\label{table:corpus_artists_materials}  \\  % <---
\toprule
\textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Samples} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\toprule
\textbf{Brand} & \textbf{Samples} \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Reference samples}} \\
\midrule
Synthesized ZnO & ZnO nanosmoke synthesized  \\
 & as in Zhang et al. (2020) \cite{zhangControlled2020} \\
\midrule
\textit{Br\"uggemann} & Two powders (2020, indirect and direct method) \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{ZnO manufacturers}} \\
\midrule
KF Chemicals & One powder (historical) \\
Japan, since 1951 &  \\
\midrule
Kremer & Two powders (2010 and 2021) \\
Germany, since 1977 &  \\
\midrule
Maastrichtsche zinkwit Maatschappij & Five powders of different grades (1907-1989) \\
The Netherlands, 1870-1989\footnote{Then acquired by the \textit{Vieille Montagne}.} & \\
\midrule
Merck & One powder (historical) \\
Germany, since 1668 & \\                                                                                                                                                                                                          \midrule
Sikkens & One powder (historical) \\
The Netherlands, since 1792 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                               \midrule
Vieille Montagne & Six powders of different grades (1847-1989) \\
Belgium, 1837-1989\footnote{Then Union Minière, today Umicore.} &  \\                                                                                                                                        \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Colour manufacturers}} \\
\midrule
Blockx & Two paint tubes (1976 and 2021) \\
Belgium, since 1865 & One titan-zinc white paint tube (2021) \\
\midrule
Bocour & One paint tube (1933-75) \\
US, since 1932 & One titan-zinc white paint jar (1940-75) \\
\midrule
Charvin & One paint tube (2010) \\
France, since 1830 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                            \midrule
Craftint Manufacturing Company & One paint tube (1950s) \\
US, 1929-2018 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                         \midrule
Fezandie \& Sperrle & One powder (historical) \\
US, until 1979 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                  \midrule
Grumbacher & Three paint tubes (1950s and two tubes from1960-75) \\
US, since 1905\footnote{Today in Chartpark, Inc.} &  \\
\midrule
Lefranc & One paint tube (1930s) \\
France, 1720-1964\footnote{Then Lefranc \& Bourgeois.} & one paint sample (1950) \\
 & One powder with a binder (before 1964) \\
\midrule
Lefranc \& Bourgeois & Two paint tubes (after 1964, 2021) \\
France, since 1964 & One pastel (after 1964) \\
\midrule
Maimeri & One paint sample from a color chart (1939-46) \\
Italy, since 1923\footnote{In Fila group since 2014.} & One paint tube (1970s) \\
\midrule
Michael Harding & One paint tube (2021) \\
US, since 1982 &  \\
\midrule
Old Holland & One paint tube (2010) \\
The Netherlands, since 1664 &  \\
\midrule
Permanent Pigments & One powder (1933-55) \\
US, 1933-55 & One paint tube (1933-55) \\
\midrule
Ripolin & One paint sample from a color chart (1900) \\
France, since 1888 &  \\
\midrule
Sennelier & Two powders (after 1887, 2021) \\
France, since 1887 & Two paint tubes (after the 1920s, 2021) \\
\midrule
Talens & Two paint tubes (1930s)\footnote{From the same box: one in good condition, the other yellowed and dried.} \\
The Netherlands, 1889-1969\footnote{Then \textit{Sikkens} group, then \textit{Akzo Nobel}.} &  \\
\midrule
Vilhelm Pacht & One paint tube (1890-1909) \\
Denmark, since 1887 &  \\
\midrule
Winsor \& Newton & One paint tube (2021) \\
UK, since 1832 &  \\
\bottomrule
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I assume, that footnotes should be part of table and not below of table. For this you should also use `threeparttable` or `longtblr` of `tabularray` package.

**Addendum:**
An example of your table when is used `longtblr` of `tabularray` package and footnotes are part of table. Also the table design is a bit changes that (to my taste) looks nice:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                              % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\NewTableCommand\subtitle[1]{%
\SetCell[c=#1]{c, font=\bfseries\itshape, bg=gray!30,
               }
                            }% end of newtblecommand

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Overview of the samples in the corpus of artists' materials.},
  label = {table:corpus_artists_materials},
note{a} = {Then acquired by the \textit{Vieille Montagne}.},
note{b} = {Then Union Minière, today Umicore.},
note{c} = {Today in Chartpark, Inc.},
note{d} = {Then Lefranc \& Bourgeois.},
note{e} = {In Fila group since 2014.},
note{d} = {Then \textit{Sikkens} group, then \textit{Akzo Nobel}.}
                    ]{colspec = {*{2}{X[l, h]} @{}},
                      row{1}  = {c, font=\bfseries},
                      rowhead = 1
                      }
% table body
    \toprule
Brand           &   Samples                 \\
    \midrule
\subtitle{2}    Reference samples   
                &                           \\
    \addlinespace
Synthesized ZnO &   ZnO nanosmoke synthesized  
                    as in Zhang et al. (2020) \cite{zhangControlled2020}    \\
    \addlinespace
\textit{Br\"uggemann} 
                & Two powders (2020, indirect and direct method)            \\
    \toprule
\subtitle{2}    ZnO manufacturers             
                &                               \\
    \addlinespace
{KF Chemicals\\    
Japan, since 1951}
                & One powder (historical        \\
    \addlinespace
{Kremer\\           
Germany, since 1977}     
                & Two powders (2010 and 2021)   \\
    \addlinespace
{Maastrichtsche zinkwit Maatschappij\\ The Netherlands, 1870-1989\TblrNote{a}.}      
                & Five powders of different grades (1907-1989)  \\
    \addlinespace
{Merck \\
Germany, since 1668}
                & One powder (historical)   \\                                                                                                                                                                                                        \addlinespace
{Sikkens \\
The Netherlands, since 1792}     
                & One powder (historical)   \\
    \addlinespace
{Vieille Montagne\\  
Belgium, 1837-1989\TblrNote{b}}  
                & Six powders of different grades (1847-1989)   \\
    \addlinespace
\subtitle{2}    Colour manufacturers    &                   \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=2]{} {Blockx \\  Belgium, since 1865}             
                & Two paint tubes (1976 and 2021)           \\
                & One titan-zinc white paint tube (2021)    \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=2]{} {Bocour\\ US, since 1932}              
                & One paint tube (1933-75)  \\
                & One titan-zinc white paint jar (1940-75) \\
    \addlinespace
{Charvin\\             
France, since 1830} & One paint tube (2010) \\
    \addlinespace
{Craftint Manufacturing Company\\ 
US, 1929-2018}      & One paint tube (1950s) \\ 
    \addlinespace
{Fezandie \& Sperrle\\
US, until 1979 }    & One powder (historical) \\
    \addlinespace
{Grumbacher\\         
US, since 1905\TblrNote{c}}     
                    & Three paint tubes (1950s and two tubes from1960-75) \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=3]{} {Lefranc\\   France, 1720-1964\TblrNote{d}}
                    & One paint tube (1930s) \\
                    & one paint sample (1950) \\
                    & One powder with a binder (before 1964)    \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=2]{} {Lefranc \& Bourgeois\\  France, since 1964}
                    & Two paint tubes (after 1964, 2021)    \\
                    & One pastel (after 1964)               \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=2]{} {Maimeri\\   Italy, since 1923\TblrNote{e}}             
                    & One paint sample from a color chart (1939-46) \\
                    & One paint tube (1970s)                    \\
    \addlinespace
{Michael Harding\\  US, since 1982}    
                    & One paint tube (2021) \\
    \addlinespace
{Old Holland\\  The Netherlands, since 1664}        
                    & One paint tube (2010)     \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=2]{} {Permanent Pigments\\US, 1933-55} 
                    & One powder (1933-55)      \\
                    & One paint tube (1933-55)  \\
    \addlinespace
{Ripolin\\  France, since 1888}            
                    & One paint sample from a color chart (1900) \\
    \addlinespace
\SetCell[r=2]{} {Sennelier\\ France, since 1887}           
                    & Two powders (after 1887, 2021) \\
                    & Two paint tubes (after the 1920s, 2021) \\
    \addlinespace
{Talens\\   The Netherlands, 1889-1969\TblrNote{f}}
                    & Two paint tubes (1930s)\footnote{From the same box: one in good condition, the other yellowed and dried.}  \\
    \addlinespace
{Vilhelm Pacht\\    Denmark, since 1887} 
                    & One paint tube (1890-1909)  \\
    \addlinespace
{Winsor \& Newton\\  UK, since 1832}    
                    & One paint tube (2021) \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the `longtable` environment; just suppress the whitespace padding at the edges and let the whitespace between the two columns be endogenous.

I would also left-align rather than center-set the cell contents, and I'd replace most `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace` to create a less-cluttered "look".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of the next few instructions
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\textwidth}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}  % see section 5 of user guide of 'longtable' package
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll @{}}

\caption{Overview of the samples in the corpus of artists' materials.}
\label{table:corpus_artists_materials}\\

\toprule
Brand & Samples \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, continued}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
Brand & Samples \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textsc{Reference samples}} \\
\addlinespace   
Synthesized ZnO & ZnO nanosmoke synthesized  \\
 & as in Zhang et~al.\ (2020) \cite{zhangControlled2020} \\
\addlinespace                                                                                    
\textit{Brüggemann} & Two powders (2020, indirect and direct method) \\

\addlinespace\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textsc{ZnO manufacturers}} \\
\addlinespace                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
KF Chemicals & One powder (historical) \\ 
Japan, since 1951 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                             
\addlinespace
Kremer & Two powders (2010 and 2021) \\
Germany, since 1977 &  \\
\addlinespace                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Maastrichtsche zinkwit Maatschappij & Five powders of different grades (1907--1989) \\
The Netherlands, 1870--1989\footnote{Then acquired by the \textit{Vieille Montagne}.} & \\                                                                                                       
\addlinespace
Merck & One powder (historical) \\
Germany, since 1668 & \\                                                                                                                                                                                                          \addlinespace
Sikkens & One powder (historical) \\
The Netherlands, since 1792 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                               \addlinespace 
Vieille Montagne & Six powders of different grades (1847--1989) \\
Belgium, 1837--1989\footnote{Then Union Minière, today Umicore.} &  \\                                                                                                                                       

\addlinespace\addlinespace
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{\textsc{Colour manufacturers}} \\   
\addlinespace                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Blockx & Two paint tubes (1976 and 2021) \\
Belgium, since 1865 & One titan-zinc white paint tube (2021) \\
\addlinespace
Bocour & One paint tube (1933--75) \\
US, since 1932 & One titan-zinc white paint jar (1940--75) \\
\addlinespace
Charvin & One paint tube (2010) \\
France, since 1830 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                            \addlinespace
Craftint Manufacturing Company & One paint tube (1950s) \\
US, 1929--2018 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                         \addlinespace
Fezandie \& Sperrle & One powder (historical) \\
US, until 1979 &  \\                                                                                                                                                                                                  \addlinespace
Grumbacher & Three paint tubes (1950s and 2 tubes from 1960--75) \\
US, since 1905\footnote{Today in Chartpark, Inc.} &  \\                                                                                                                                      
\addlinespace
Lefranc & One paint tube (1930s) \\
France, 1720--1964\footnote{Then Lefranc \& Bourgeois.} & One paint sample (1950) \\
 & One powder with a binder (before 1964) \\
\addlinespace
Lefranc \& Bourgeois & Two paint tubes (after 1964, 2021) \\
France, since 1964 & One pastel (after 1964) \\
\addlinespace
Maimeri & One paint sample from a color chart (1939--46) \\*
Italy, since 1923\footnote{In Fila group since 2014.} & One paint tube (1970s) \\
\addlinespace
Michael Harding & One paint tube (2021) \\*
US, since 1982 &  \\
\addlinespace
Old Holland & One paint tube (2010) \\*
The Netherlands, since 1664 &  \\
\addlinespace
Permanent Pigments & One powder (1933--55) \\*
US, 1933--55 & One paint tube (1933--55) \\
\addlinespace
Ripolin & One paint sample from a color chart (1900) \\*
France, since 1888 &  \\
\addlinespace
Sennelier & Two powders (after 1887, 2021) \\*
France, since 1887 & Two paint tubes (after the 1920s, 2021) \\
\addlinespace
Talens & Two paint tubes (1930s)\footnote{From the same box: one in good condition, the other yellowed and dried.} \\
The Netherlands, 1889--1969\footnote{Then \textit{Sikkens} group, then \textit{Akzo Nobel}.} &  \\
\addlinespace
Vilhelm Pacht & One paint tube (1890--1909) \\
Denmark, since 1887 &  \\
\addlinespace                                                                                                                                                                                           
Winsor \& Newton & One paint tube (2021) \\
UK, since 1832 &  \\


\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```